# SpriteKit - Quiz game passing array of questions and answers

Tags: swift

I'm wondering how to go about implementing the following:

Create an array of questions, and also manage the correct answer i.e.

```
var question = ["What colour is the sky?"]

var answers = ["Blue", "Yellow", "Black", "Green"]
```

I've got the logic of my SpriteKit set up, where users can tap etc. However, I cannot seem to find anything online which can help me.

Essentially, I want to display a question and for each question generate a SKLabelNode for the answers. If the answer is correct then progress to the next question. I just can't understand how to go about it. Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need a model for your question:

```
class Question {
 
  let question: String
  let answerA: String
  let answerB: String
  let answerC: String
  let answerD: String
  let correctAnswer: Int
    
  init(questionText: String, choiceA: String, choiceB: String, choiceC:String, choiceD:String, answer: Int){
    question = questionText
    answerA = choiceA
    answerB = choiceB
    answerC = choiceC
    answerD = choiceD
    correctAnswer = answer
    
  } 
}
```

And a QuestionBank class:

```
class QuestionBank {

   var list = [Question]()

   init(){
     
     list.append(Question(questionText:"What colour is the sky?", choiceA: "Blue", choiceB: "Yellow", choiceC: "Black", choiceD: "Green", answer: 1))

     //Add more questions to your array here

   }
  
 }
```

In your ViewController class:

```
  let questions = QuestionBank()
  var questionNumber = 0
  var correctButtonAnswer = 0

  questionLabel.text = questions.list[questionNumber].question
  answerAButton.setTitle(questions.list[questionNumber].answerA, for: UIControl.State.normal)
  answerBButton.setTitle(questions.list[questionNumber].answerB, for: UIControl.State.normal)
  answerCButton.setTitle(questions.list[questionNumber].answerC, for: UIControl.State.normal)
  answerDButton.setTitle(questions.list[questionNumber].answerD, for: UIControl.State.normal)
  correctButtonAnswer = questions.list[questionNumber}.correctAnswer
```

Obviously you have to add logic to make it work.